Directus and Nuxt: Correct items frontend output
I am using this tutorial for testing a Directus/Nuxt project: https://docs.directus.io/blog/nuxt-directus-getting-started.html
I modified the code because I have a collection called "playgrounds".
<template>
    {{ playgrounds }}
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const { getItems } = useDirectusItems();

interface Playground {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

const playgrounds = await getItems<Playground>({
    collection: "playgrounds"
});
</script>

I get a 404 error message with the code above and it only works when I delete these lines:
const playgrounds = await getItems<Playground>({
    collection: "playgrounds"
});

However, "playgounds" are still not being displayed (listed).
Any hints where to dig?
